# How to PvP in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I just bought Dark Souls 3 for PS4 and played like 3 hours. But I cant seem to find PvP option in the menus. Do I have to finish the campaign first? Can someone tell me how  to access PvP from scratch?

Answer (score 7):

The fastest way to start PvP is to reach the second bonfire at the High Wall of Lothric, then return to Firelink Shrine. When you return, there should be an NPC named Leonhard leaning against Lothric's throne. He will give you [Cracked Red Eye Orbs](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Cracked+Red+Eye+Orb), which are one-time-use items that allow you to invade another player's world. You can get more of these items from the dark wraiths near the Farron Keep Perimeter. If you continue to follow Leonhard's questline, you'll eventually get a [Red Eye Orb](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Red+Eye+Orb), which can be used an infinite number of times to invade.

You can also get the [Red Sign Soapstone](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Red+Sign+Soapstone) from a spell-casting worm outside of the Rosaria's Bedchamber bonfire (in Cathedral of the Deep), which allows you to be *summoned* for PvP in other people's worlds. If you see a summon sign that is red, it means that someone else used the Red Sign Soapstone -- if you interact with the red summon sign, you can summon them into your world for PvP.

There are also covenants you can join that will auto-summon you to other people's worlds for PvP. These covenants include the Watchdogs of Farron, Blue Sentinels, Aldritch Faithful, and Blades of the Darkmoon.

Comment: @CanDemirel Glad to have helped! When you see all the answers that come in, feel free to pick one you're satisfied with (or found the most helpful) by selecting the checkmark next to it. Long may the sun shine!

Comment: One tiny side note to add, is when you get invaded, which is also PVP. You must be Embered to be invaded. This includes a particular boss related to a covenant, the Spears of the Church, where you can fight an NPC if you are un-embered or "offline" but if you are online/Embered you might see a Spear of the Church summoned in... (This is from the Ringed City DLC.). You might also look into the Dried Fingers, which reset your personal invasion timer (allows new invaders to show up) and increase the total player slots in your current world. You can have more summons, but also more invaders.

Comment: Oh, and I suppose there is the new Duel menu also obtainable from the DLC, where you can access a traditional match making style multiplayer menu from the Shrine Bonfire which offers a few different game types. There is Duel which omits Estus and limits Ashen Estus in one on one combat, 2-6 player brawl, and 2v2 or 3v3 teams.

Comment: Following up on @ZealousHypocrites: that duel mode is called Undead Match and is unlocked after beating the boss *Champion's Gravetender* from the *Ashes of Ariandel DLC* – as mentioned here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/316365/211603.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls3/comments/4i8dcj/a_guide_to_getting_started_and_improving_in_dark/) is a great Reddit thread that may help you:

> So before you can even start to PvP, you need to know where everybody is scrappin'. The most popular location at the current moment is right outside of the Pontiff Sulyvahn Bonfire in Irithyll of the Boreal Valley. Immediately past the bonfire on that little balcony/open area you will see tons of summon signs. It is a great place both for spectating and fighting. Just place your sign there or summon other phantoms.

In addition, here are some guidelines for beginners:

> Due to the fact that multiplayer is kind of like a side feature, it is not extremely fleshed out. There is no arena or official place to actually do strictly PvP. So, because of this, the community has made up a set of guide lines and rules that are sort of secretly understood among players. If you are doing invasions, anything goes. You do whatever you want or need to win, but when you are being summoned from a Red Sign Soapstone or you summon a phantom, they are expecting a duel with some small set rules. Acknowledge your opponent. This isn't really necessary, but more of a courtesy and etiquette. Do a wave gesture, bow, beckon. Hell, even throwing down a hello carving is fine. If your opponent is gesturing do not attack them until they are ready to go, it's rather rude. Now, there really are not a lot of rules. The biggest one is really 'no healing.' Some people might see this as silly but healing doesn't necessarily help you get better as a player. You play a lot sloppy knowing you have free heals. Plus, if both players are healing, the host has a huge advantage because they have double the estus you do. Your estus is halved when you are summoned to another world or invade. Plus, it would make duels just last way too long. This is especially annoying in fight clubs when other people are in line for a round in the ring. Also, if you are losing don't turn tail and try to book it to the boss or something like that. Just take your loss and learn from the mistakes.

Comment: Ever since the release of the DLC's, that second comment is outdated. Please update your answer. It is still a "side feature" though, but there are places now for doing PVP only, such as the Undead Match.

Answer (score 1):

The first DLC, *Ashes of Ariandel*, introduced dedicated PvP arenas to the game: Undead Match.

Undead Match is accessible from the bonfire in Firelink Shrine, but you need to acquire *Champion's Bones* and burn them in that bonfire first.

*Champion's Bones* are obtainable in the following DLC locations: either from killing the *Champion's Gravetender & Gravetender Greatwolf* boss in [Painted World of Ariandel](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Painted+World+of+Ariandel) or after completing [Lapp](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Lapp)'s quest line in the Ringed City DLC (but only if you don't own the first DLC).