# How is Online Matchmaking calculated in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: dark-souls-3

### Question

I remember in DS1 matchmaking was linked to the maximum upgraded weapon you have in your inventory, but the streamers I follow only mention Soul Levels while playing online. Does Soul Level (SL) play a part in online matchmaking? How about weapon upgrades?

Please share sources in your answer, so that people can read up on it.

### Context

I capped my level at SL 35 (as a personal PvE challenge), but recently upgraded my main weapon to +10. I now notice that the online play on this character is almost non-existing, both invasions and summons.

---

Related:

- [How to PvP in Dark Souls 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282103/how-to-pvp-in-dark-souls-3)
- [Why/how do people have Ringed City weapons as early as Farron Keep?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/310585/why-how-do-people-have-ringed-city-weapons-as-early-as-farron-keep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Dark Souls 3 wiki](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Summon+Range+Calculator), matchmaking uses Soul Level (SL) AND Upgrade Level (UL) of weapons:

> **Dark Souls 3 uses Soul Level + Upgrade Level to determine multiplayer ranges.** If  a player has a weapon at +10, they can be matched with players who have +8 or more. If a player has no upgrades, they can be paired with players with up to +1 weapons.
>   Players have deduced that weapons that only go to +5 operate as double their numbers. So +1 is +2, +2 is +4, etc.

The wiki continues in offering tables with optimal combinations of SL and UL, both for Co-Op and Invasions. Note that the wiki adds another parameter that influences matchmaking: location.

In your case, the tables recommend to level up your character to at least level 60 (because you already have UL +10), or starting a new character where you cap the SL at 30-34 and the UL at +3 (if that is your preferred SL to be at).